# mount error(13): Permission denied - when mounting azure storageaccount fileshare to redhat linux server

Tags: linux, azure, redhat, azure-storage-account, azure-file-share

mount error(13): Permission denied - when mounting azure storageaccount fileshare to redhat linux server

I tried

```html
sudo mount //<storageaccount name>/<sharename> /<mountpoint> -o username=<userid> -t cifs,vers=3.0
```

I need someone who can help fixing this issue and provide correct syntax

Comment: I tried sudo mount //storageaccount-name/sharename /mountpoint -o username=userid -t cifs,vers=3.0

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions. Your question fits https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct. You can also store the credentials in a file (e.g. `/etc/credentials/myshare.cred`) and mount it like this:

```
sudo mount.cifs //storageaccount/myshare /myshare -o _netdev,credentials=/etc/credentials/myshare.cred --verbose
```

Assuming you're sure the credentials are correct and permissions on the share was setup correctly... (and tested from a Windows system for example) You're probably experiencing SMB protocol compatibility issues (which will result in the same error message). Are you trying to mount it on a RHEL7 system? If so, try the same mount command on a RHEL8 system and see if that works. See [Mount SMB Azure file share on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux) for more details on which SMB protocols are supported.